# setting class and other attributes for spring form tag element

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have the following page and it does not load

```
<form:form action="/test.htm"  method="post" commandName="demoForm" >

<div id="testSection" style="margin-top: 1.5%;margin-left: 3.5%;">

    <span class="test-container">
            <label>UserName</label>
            <span class="test-container-right">
                <form:input path="username" value="${UNAME}"  class="text simpleTextField" maxlength="200" style="width:60%" disabled/>
            </span>
    </span>

    <span style="width:auto; padding-left: 30%; padding-bottom: 4%; text-align:center; float:right; clear:both;">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" style="width:auto;" value="Save" />
    </span>     

</div>

</form:form>
```

but when I change it to

```
...
<span class="test-container-right">
        <form:input path="username" />
</span>
...
```

it works and loads correctly. Why am I not allowed to set html properties for form:input spring tag. How can I achieve this? On inspecting the element it expands to be

```
<input id="username" type="text" value="" name="username"></input>
```

I need to populate its value as well as provide it with a class and additional attributes like width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I resolved some part of it. Looks like tags used inside form:input tag are different than regular html tags. All of them are listed [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.input). For ex `style` is `cssStyle`.

So I change my code to

`<form:input path="username" cssClass="text simpleTextField" maxlength="200" cssStyle="width:60%" disabled="true"/>`

and now it works..

I still don't know how to populate value in this input. These seems no equivalent of `value` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

@Aniket You actually have an equivalent , consider in a case you have to  populate the `select` box with the values from the model attribute . You can make use of `items` attribute.

For instance ,

```
     <tr>
      <td>City :</td>
      <td><form:select path="city" items="${cityList}" /></td>
     </tr>
```

It will generate the select with the the list of objects.
`cityList` here refers the object that has been sent from the server side.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Yes there are equivalent tags. Tx!